# NTLM authentication on Squid proxy

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, ntlm, squid, ntlm-authentication

I am new to Squid proxy and need help in setting up NTLM authentication.
I checked so many resources on the web but did not find exact steps to get my work done
Since I have no background on proxy/networking configurations, I am not able to figure out where I am missing. I need this for some testing purpose.

Scenario:

I have, two machines
Machine 1: 
Windows Server 2012R2 on which Squid proxy server 2.6 is deployed. This machine has Active directory domain configured (domain1.com).
domain1.com has user-1 and user-2 users.

Machine 2: Is a part of domain1.com. Machine 1 acts as a proxy for Machine 2 (Manual proxy set on Machine2s Internet explorer).
Windows Integrated Authentication is turned ON in Internet Explorer menu.

I am trying to access google.com from Machine 2, IE prompts for authentication. I am providing user-1 credentials here. However, the request is not getting succeeded. Authentication prompt is appearing again and again.

---

### Squid.conf

```
auth_param ntlm program C:/squid/libexec/mswin_ntlm_auth.exe --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp
auth_param ntlm children 5
auth_param ntlm keep_alive on
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl KnownUsers proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow KnownUsers
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
```

---

access.log:

```
1528144397.050     24 XX.XX.XXX.XXX TCP_DENIED/407 2151 CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 - NONE/- text/html
1528144397.056      5 XX.XX.XXX.XXX TCP_DENIED/407 1817 CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 - NONE/- text/html
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: For one thing, you need to post the relevant snippets from your error log in this question.

Comment: I have pasted access.log statements. There are no errors observed in event viewer logs.
Is there anything needs to be done on domain controller side?
Or are there any pre-requisites that need to be fulfilled before coming on to the Squid configurations?